# PyCharm not detecting unresolved references [Django]

Tags: python, python-3.x, pycharm, virtualenv, django-1.10

So I'm having a problem with PyCharm and can't find a solution for it.
It fails to recognize unresolved references:

[image: example]

The image also shows that it fails to auto-complete *request.session*. It only happens with *.session*, it works with every other attribute.

Also, this image shows that it does detect unresolved references for other stuff:

[image: this image]

I'm running it on a virtualenv, the interpreter is configured correctly and I have Django Support enabled.

Oh, and I'm using Python3 and Django 1.10.2

**EDIT:** Just tried it with other projects. It doesn't work with Django 1.10.x but works with Django 1.9.x

Comment: Should this be a bug report to PyCharm?

Comment: @JeffBridgman I'm not sure if it's a bug or if I'm missing something, since it was working fine yesterday.

Comment: I'm a loyal Jetbrains customer and they have outstanding official support channels.

Comment: @PauloScardine I'll head there then, thank you! :)

Answer (score 0):

Well, in your 1st example `request` is a parameter to the `dummy_view` function - how would Pycharm know what type it is in order to check unresolved references (or offer auto-completion suggestions)?

You could add a check for `request`'s type (also maybe a good idea to prevent bugs):

```
def dummy_view(request):
    assert isinstance(request, ExpectedClassType)
```

Or, since you tagged your question with `python-3.x` you could also use [type hinting](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html):

```
def dummy_view(request: ExpectedClassType):
```

Comment: It does know, it has Django support. It works perfectly on projects with earlier versions of Django.
I'll type hint the parameter while this possible bug isn't fixed, thanks :)

Comment: I'm not talking about Django support - which would matter but only if the variable type would be known (and can then be looked up in Django support), I'm talking about the **actual code context**. Use the **exact** same code when comparing with the earlier versions, not like you do in this question where you compare undefined reference checking in 2 different contextes: an unknown parameter (local variable) which can be anything vs. a known class instance.